# Any sequence of real numbers has a monotone subsequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

**I'm aware that other posts have discussed the same issue. I would like feedback on my specific proof. Thank you :)**

---

Consider any sequence $(x_n).$

A "peak" element is an element such that all elements $x_i$ that succeed it in the sequence are no greater than it. In other words, an element $x_p$ is a "peak" element if for all $i > p_1,$ it is the case that $x_{p_1} \geq x_i.$

In the sequence $(x_n),$ either there are finitely many peaks, or there are infinitely many.

If there are finitely many, then there is a peak element $x_p$ that appears last. Then, for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $i > p,$ there exists some $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M > i$ and $x_M > x_i.$ In such a case, there clearly exists a monotone *increasing* subsequence $(x_{n_i}).$

If there are infinitely many peaks, then there clearly exists a monotone *decreasing* subsequence,

$$x_{p_1}, x_{p_2}, x_{p_3}, \ldots$$

where $x_{p_1} \geq x_{p_2} \geq x_{p_3} \geq \cdots$ are all peak elements.

Hence, any sequence has some subsequence that is monotone, whether increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Right out of Bartle and Sherbert.

Comment: Glad it seems that way

Comment: Thanks Charlie!

Comment: You can perhaps clean up the exposition by saying either there are infinitely any peak elements or only finitely many...

Comment: Hey, David. Thank you for your feedback. I agree and will change it.

Comment: As an annoying special case, you need to handle the possibility that there are _no_ peak elements (because then you can't say that there is a peak element $x_p$ that appears last).

Comment: If you want feedback on your specific proof, then you should add the [tag:proof-verification] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any sequence $(x_n).$

A "peak" element is an element such that all elements $x_i$ that succeed it in the sequence are no greater than it. In other words, an element $x_p$ is a "peak" element if for all $i > p,$ it is the case that $x_{p} \geq x_i.$

In the sequence $(x_n),$ either there are finitely many peaks, or there are infinitely many.

If there are finitely many, then there is a peak element $x_p$ that appears last. Then, for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $i > p,$ there exists some $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M > i$ and $x_M > x_i.$ In such a case, there clearly exists a monotone *increasing* subsequence $(x_{n_i}).$

If there are infinitely many peaks, then there clearly exists a monotone *decreasing* subsequence,

$$x_{p_1}, x_{p_2}, x_{p_3}, \ldots$$

where $x_{p_1} \geq x_{p_2} \geq x_{p_3} \geq \cdots$ are all peak elements.

Hence, any sequence has some subsequence that is monotone, whether increasing or decreasing.

Comment: I have made a small tweak. At the moment when you wrote "$p_1$", nothing was defined for it; you had defined $p$ by mentioning $x_p$, so you should use $p$ throughout that sentence.